# Tensoflow: How to solve "ImportError: libcudnn.so.6:"

Tags: tensorflow

i used tensorflow ver0.12.0. i wanna use ver 0.10 so i run `pip install tensorflow`

then when i use tensorflow ,

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_zooms_training.py", line 6, in

from keras.models import Sequential

File "/home/satan/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/**init**.py", line 2, in 
    from . import backend

........

ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
`

this error is happend .
Please tell me how to solve.
Thank you for your help.

## enviroment

ubuntu14.04

python2.7

Comment: you need to install cuDNN v6. check out [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12416)

Answer (score 2):

download libcudnn.so.6 in https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn.
put it to /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ folder
and use next commond

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx libcudnn.so.6.5.18
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.6.5.18 libcudnn.so.6
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.6 libcudnn.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Change directory to
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/